# How to open a connection to a SQL Server database that is already in use in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database-connection, sql-server-2012

I connect to the database in asp.net mvc 3 project. Also I have a windows service project in my solution which on some event writes the data into this database.

The difficulty is that when the code from windows service project needs to connect to the database I get `SqlException`:

> *Cannot open database "WebStore" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.*

Here is the code from windows service:

```
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; DataBase=WebStore; 
                AttachDbFilename=myDbFullPath;
                Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    }
```

And in the event handler that writes to the database:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    conn.Open();
    var productId = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(e.Name, @"\d+").Value);
    const string cmd1 = "UPDATE Products SET ImageModifiedDate=@date WHERE ProductId=@productId";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(cmd1, conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productId", productId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
```

The exception occurs in `conn.Open();` line. If I comment this line new exception will occur in `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`:

> *InvalidOperationException: Opened and available connection is needed for ExecuteNonQuery. Connection is closed.*

**Question:** How to open a connection to the SQL Server database that is already attached in another project?

**Edit 1:** I use the following code to create new login and new user in my DB:

```
CREATE LOGIN user1
WITH PASSWORD = 'password1';
GO
CREATE USER user1 FOR LOGIN user1;
GO
```

Than I'm trying to attach my DB in Server Explorer: I choose "Use Sql Server Autherntication" and enter user name: user1, password: password1.

And I get:

> *The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information:
>
>   Login failed for user 'user1'.*

**Edit 2:** I set this properties:

```
processInstaller.Username = "user1";
processInstaller.Password = "password1";
```

and than run in cmd:

```
installutil /name=user1 /password=password1 MyService.exe
```

and I get *`System.ComponentModel.Win32.Exception:`*
*`the comparison between user names and security identifiers haven't been executed.`*

What do I do wrong?

**Edit 3:**  I set my username and password in services.msc and processInstaller "Account" property I left with "Local System". It runs but when I change the image (and the event handler trying to access my database) I get:

*`Cannot attach file 'C:\Users\Aleksey\repos\working-copy\WebStore\WebStore\App_Data\WebStore.mdf' as database 'WebStore' because this file is already in use for database 'C:\USERS\ALEKSEY\REPOS\WORKING-COPY\WEBSTORE\WEBSTORE\APP_DATA\WEBSTORE.MDF',`*

In the connection string I added credentials of user which I've created in the database:

*`User Id=user1;PASSWORD=password1;`*

Besides, when I'm trying to add connection in server explorer and use `Sql Server Authentication` and I enter `user1` and `password1` I get the message from ***Edit 1***.

Should I use in server explorer `*Windows Authentication*` and in windows service in the connection string: *`User Id=user1;PASSWORD=password1;`* ?

Comment: does the login exception still happen when you debug the code under your own credentials/identity?  Also, I rarely use the @ directive on strings, does that change the behavior of the '\' such that '\v' is correct or should it be '\\v'?  (Again, I rarely use the @ and do not know.)

Comment: Create new login in the database and pass user name and password in the connection string.

Comment: Have you tried opening it with the network service account? That account should bypass traditional logins. As it will act like the computer on the network, so it shouldn't have an issue interfacing with SQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I haven't tried to open it with the network service account. Will check the link

Comment: Does the System user have log in rights to your sql server, and does it have permission to the WebStore DB?  Your windows service is running as this user and trying to connect with those credentials.  I don't think the problem is two simultaneous connections.  You can also change who your service runs as through its properties.

Comment: @Mike_Matthews_II The @ directive doesn't change the behavior but it does ignore special characters so you may have to add an additional \ as it may ignore one of them.

Comment: @ Brent Stewart, In ServiceProcessInstaller's "Account" property I selected "LocalSystem".

Comment: @Greg, if I disconnect from the DB in Server Explorer everything will work, so the connection string is correct. But of course I need both projects work simultaneously. Besides, I have another console app in solution that uploads large amount of data into DB and I remember that I needed to disconnect from the DB in web project to run console project.

Comment: does the user account you're using to connect have a connection limit set? It may be that this is causing your problem if the SSMS has the connection open before your code

Comment: If Greg is correct in affirming my assumption, then it would seem your connectionstring is bogus.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cannot open database "WebStore" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
```

This happens because your service is running with the LocalSystem account, and you're using integrated security to connect to SQL server, and SYSTEM shouldn't have access there. So threechoices:

1. Switch to SQL Server authentication. That includes creating a login in the database and modifying the connection string
2. Run the service with a particular user with the only the privileges it really needs (this is actually a good idea) and give that user access to the database so it can connect with integrated security. This is the easiest because it doesn't require any changes to the code
3. If you really need to run as SYSTEM, then can use impersonation to switch to another user (like the user from option 2) with LogonUser. That way you end up in option 2 just for the database access and retain SYSTEM priviliveges for the rest of the service code.

The second error

```
InvalidOperationException: Opened and available connection is needed for ExecuteNonQuery. Connection is closed.
```

Is caused by the first error, failure to open the connection brings this up. You can't execute anything without an open connection, ADO.Net makes sure of that.

So the first error is the only one that matters.

I recomend that you go with option two as is the best in terms of security practices, and since you are running in integrated security you don't have to store any password, and thats a plus when you have your application in several environments with different databases, users, passwords and what have you. Just a user per enviroment, permissions and you're set.

Comment: How exactly to implement second approach? Please, check my edits above. Thanks!

Comment: Don't set the user on the installation, run services.msc and edit the service properties there

Comment: Can You describe the process step by step, cause I don't completely get how and what to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run services.msc as an administrative user. Locate your service, double click, go to the log on tab, change from local system to "This Account", put a user that has access to sql server with integrated security